# What is 'x' behind the 'if' in the 2nd row mean?

Tags: string

```
str_list = ["Emma", "Jon", "", "Kelly", None, "Eric", ""]
str_list = [x for x in str_list if x]
print(str_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python supports the concepts of "truthy," meaning a value treated as logically true, and "falsey," a value logically treated as false.  As it turns out, empty string is falsey, so the `if x` condition in the list comprehension will *exclude* empty string values.

Answer (score 0):

Here, checking `if x` is implicitly looking at `bool(x)`. Specifically, notice that when `x` is an empty string, `bool(x)` is false: we say that it is "falsy." You can see this for yourself interactively:

```py
>>> bool("Emma")
True
>>> bool("")
False
>>>
```

This list comprehension effectively filters out these "falsy" values, or in this case, empty strings.

For more about common truth values and how to customize your own, see [the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#booleans).